# wrapping href around implode variable

Tags: php, syntax, implode

I have a php implode function to list wordpress custom field keys which works great. The problem is I need to wrap the web urls in an href to make them clickable and can't wrap my head around the function sytnax. The key value is in this format www.site.com, so I had it set up for a single entry like so:

```
<?php if(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'website', true)): ?>
    <strong>Website:</strong> <a href="http://<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'website', true); ?>" target="_blank"><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'website', true); ?></a>
<?php endif; ?>
```

but now we need to be able to hold multiple entries separated by a comma. Here is the code that works, but does not output a clickable url:

```
<?php
if( $website = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'website') ):
    $label = count( $website ) > 1 ? 'Websites' : 'Website';
    ?>
    <strong><?php echo $label; ?>:</strong> <?php echo implode( $website, ', ' ); ?><br />
    <?php
endif;
?>
```

This is what I've been playing with, which is clearly wrong

```
<?php echo '<a href="http://' . implode('" target="_blank">', $website) . "</a>" . ', '; ?><br />
```

Even if it *did* work, it would only output the url, not the text that is linked.

--------------------- EDIT -------------------------

Kai's answer was closest, so I marked it the answer, but it didn't include the label variable. By marrying two of them I came up with this answer which works beautifully

```
<?php
    if( $website = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'website') ):
        $label = count( $website ) > 1 ? 'Websites' : 'Website';
        $links = array_map(
            function($url) {
                 $url = htmlspecialchars($url);
                 return sprintf ('<a href="http://%s">%s</a>', $url, $url);
            },
            $website);
        ?>
        <strong><?php echo $label; ?>:</strong> <?php echo implode(', ', $links); ?><br />
<?php endif ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could seriously abuse `implode` in a manner similar to what you have tried yourself and make it work, but that's really not a good idea.

What you want is to move from a list of URLs to a list of anchor tags, which is possible with [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php):

```
if ($website = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'website')) {
    $links = array_map(
        function($url) {
             $url = htmlspecialchars($url);
             return sprintf ('<a href="http://%s">%s</a>', $url, $url);
        },
        $website);

    echo implode(', ', $links);
}
```

Comment: i'm in a code editor so it doesn't "say" anything, it just has a warning color next to it and all the colors for the code below it changes. i tried adding a semicolon to the last curly bracket but it didn't like that either. would you mind editing it to include the `<?php` bits? maybe i'm just wee todd head and aren't implementing it correctly?

Comment: The problem I was having is that there was an `<?php endif; ?>` after this and apparently that isn't needed. This solution is awesome, however it leaves out the label `Website: `

Comment: This was closest so i marked it the answer, however since it didn't include the label variable I edited the original question to include the final solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
if( $website = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'website') ):
    $label = count( $website ) > 1 ? 'Websites' : 'Website';
    ?>
    <strong><?php echo $label; ?>:</strong> 
    <?php foreach($website AS $w): ?>
        <a href="<?php echo $w; ?>" target="_blank"><?php echo $w; ?></a> <br />
    <?php endforeach; ?>      
<?php endif; ?>
```

This makes the assumption that every "website" in your array is a full valid url including http://

I think the root of the problem here is understanding what [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) does and why it wouldn't work the way you want.

**EDIT:**

I see, you want them in an inline list separated by commas. You should use Jon's method then since it will do what you want more elegantly than what I've suggested here.

Comment: this returns the values but does not account for the comma... if i add a comma to the function it adds it to every url including the last one. you're right about not understanding implode. i am lernening!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a decorator pattern. Modify the example below to fit your needs

```
interface HtmlElementInterface {
    public function getText();
    public function render();
}

class LinkDecorator implements HtmlElementInterface {

    protected $title;
    protected $text;

    public function __construct($text, $title, $renderNow = false) {
        if (!is_string($text) || empty($text)) {
            throw new InvalidArgumentException("The text of the element must be a non-empty string.");
        }
        $this->text = $text;
        $this->title = $title;
        if ($renderNow) {
            echo $this->render();
        }
    }

    public function getText() {
        return $this->text;
    }

    public function render() {
        // do your magic here
        return "<a href='" . $this->text . "'>" . $this->title . "</a>";
    }

}
```